# How do I display bar plot for values that are zero in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-dash, plotly-python

How do I make the bar appear when one of the value of y is zero? It just leaves a gap by default. Is there a way I can enable it to plot for zero values? I am able to see a line on the x-axis at `y=0` for the same if just plotted using `go.Box`. I would like to see this in the Bar plot as well.
So far, I set the base to zero. But that doesn't plot for y=0 either.
Here is my sample code. My actual code contains multiple traces, that's why I would like to see the plot for y=0
Here is the sample python code:

```
 import plotly.graph_objects as go
 fig = go.Figure()
 fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[0, 3, 2]))
 fig.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bar charts come with a line around the bars that by default are set to the same color as the background. In your case `'#E5ECF6'`. If you change that, the line will appear as a border around each bar that will remain visible even when `y = 0` for any given `x`.

```
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color = 'blue', marker_line_width = 12)
```

If you set the line color to match that of the bar itself, you'll get this:

#### Plot 1: Bars with identical fill and line colors

[image]

If I understand correctly, this should be pretty close to what you're trying to achieve. At least visually. I would perhaps consider adjusting the `yaxis range` a bit to make it a bit clearer that the y value displayed is in fact `0`.

#### Plot 2: Adjusted y axis and separate colors

[image]

#### Complete code for Plot 1:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[0, 3, 2], marker_color = 'blue'))
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color = 'blue', marker_line_width = 12)
fig.show()
```

#### Complete code for Plot 2:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[0, 3, 2], marker_color =  '#00CC96'))
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color = '#636EFA', marker_line_width = 4)

fig.update_yaxes(range=[-1, 4])
fig.show()
```

---

#### Edit after comments

Just to verify that the line color is the same as the background color using plotly version `5.4.0`

#### Plot 1:

[image]

#### Plot 2: Zoomed in

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. Very close to what I was looking for. But, if the line around the borders are by default has same color as background, then by increasing just the `marker_line_width` arg the line at y axis should become visible, correct? But looks like it would still be invisible if you don't explicitly set the marker_line_color.

Comment: @KiranPrakash You may experience different behavior on different versions of Plotly. I'm on `5.4.0`. I'll include some details in my answer.

Comment: You are right, I had to zoom in. I was using 5.3.0 and upgraded to 5.5.0. Thanks for the edits. Isn't there a way to tell plotly to auto-pick the border color same as plot color instead of setting background color? The box plot for the same, chooses the border color little darker than the plot by default.

Comment: What I meant in my previous comment is that, if there is a way to set the marker_line_color = marker_color automatically. One way would be to use the color code from the figure object. But that gets complicated with stacked bar plot containing wide data formats.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to create a *border* using **marker**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[0, 3, 2])).update_traces(
    marker={"line": {"width": 3, "color": "rgb(0,0,0)"}}
).update_layout(yaxis={"range": [-1, 4]})
```

[image]